# In Android Studio, how can I follow/unfollow a Github user using Github API?

Tags: android

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.following_tab, container, false);

        followingListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.following_list);

        followingListItems = new ArrayList<>();

        userNameList = new ArrayList<>();
        imageUrlList = new ArrayList<>();

        adapter = new RelatedUserListAdapter(getContext(), followingListItems);
        followingListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // viewPager for navigating to another tab without clicking on the tab itself
        viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.container);

        // Enables opening the GitHub webpage of the following page

        followingListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://github.com/" + userNameList.get(position));
                //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                //startActivity(intent);
                SM.sendDataToProfile(userNameList.get(position));
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            }
        });

        new JSONTask().execute(APIURL);

        return view;

    }
```

This is a code of my fragment that represents a list of users that I am following. It was retrieved by calling Github API (https://api.github.com/users/whyjay17/following), and I want to make the user to follow/unfollow by clicking it (clicking is handled in the setOnItemClickListener).Right now, I have the username of the Following page retrieved. How can I make follow/unfollow the user?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make an call to GitHub's REST API.

```
PUT /user/following/:username
```

> Following a user requires the user to be logged in and authenticated with basic auth or OAuth with the user:follow scope.

Check the documentation of GitHub API for followers at: https://developer.github.com/v3/users/followers/

To make a PUT API call, use the same way as you did while retrieving followers and use following code:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
```

Comment: Thank you! But I am confused how to make this work in Android Studio which uses Java. Because the link that you provided doesn't show a Java code. I am new to this, so could you please elaborate?

Comment: Your edit seems to make sense for me. But I have two remaining questions. To represent "PUT /user/following/:username" this part in Java code, what do we have to put after httpCon.setRequestMethod("PUT") ? Also, how can we log in as an authenticated user in our android app?

Comment: That is a very broad question. Please read the android/java documentation for how to make an API call. Also read about GitHub OAuth at https://developer.github.com/apps/building-integrations/setting-up-and-registering-oauth-apps/